# Object required error, copy paste loop

Tags: vba, copy-paste

I am trying to copy a range from one sheet to the other but can not get the code to run with out an error(object-required). Can someone please correct where I am going wrong.

In addition I need this code to repeat this process 20 times; I want this list to have 20 duplicates of each value. should I just make a loop and run this code 20 times? Or is there a faster way to do this?

Thank you.

```
Sub Update_FSKU()

'Range of list in Final Good Tab
Dim TrowFG As Integer
Dim BrowFG As Integer

'Range of Existing List in Final Tab
Dim TrowF As Integer
Dim BrowF As Integer

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
BrowF = (ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) + 1
Worksheets("Finished Good").Activate
TrowFG = 2
BrowFG = (ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) + 1

Range("A2:" & "B" & BrowFG).Copy

Sheets("Final").Activate.Range("A" & BrowF).PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activate doesn't return a value, so you can't chain `.Range()` onto it.

Try:

```
Sheets("Final").Range("A" & BrowF).PasteSpecial
```